# How to create dropdown like shown in screenshot

Tags: android

Right now I am using spinner but spinner look is different. I want dropdown list shown in screen 
[image]
Please help

Comment: This looks like a custom annimation to me. When you take a look at the spinner's code you'll probably see `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item` which I think it the layout for the dropdown menu. I think that you can modify the existing one and use the modified for your needs, but the one you showed here is not a default one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think below both link might help you :

https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction

https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction3D

Comment: Is there anything different from links included in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Why you want to implement like this if it can be done in default way.

Still here is one detailed example to create Quick action dialog:
[How to Create QuickAction Dialog in Android](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/) or [NewQuickAction](https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction).

**Update:**

You can use native [PopupMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html) for displaying options in the same as mentioned above.

Comment: Can you give me link of a tutorial for the default way?

Comment: @CompaqLE2202x check updated detail.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create like that you need use dialog.. it will display as what u want. Consider down arrow as a button. And the items are displayed as list view.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity  {
      Button dialogButton;
       Dialog dialog;
String[] gender={"Male","Female"};
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      {
       dialogButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.dialog_button);
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
            showDialogMatch();
        }
    });


protected void showDialogMatch() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    dialog=new Dialog(this);

    dialog = new Dialog(this,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.match_type_dialog);
     LayoutParams lp=dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();    
     lp.x=260;lp.y=350;lp.width=280;lp.height=280;lp.gravity=Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.LEFT;
    lp.dimAmount=0;            
    lp.flags=LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS | LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL;
    dialog.show();
    ListView lvview=(ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,gender);
    lvview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

}

And your match_type_dialog xml is like this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="@drawable/switch_base">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

Comment: have you tried the above code....

Comment: How do I do this where it displays nearby the EditText selected like on the screenshot?